# Purpose of the code 200

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

What is the purpose of the code 200? I was wondering why they sometimes post to **twitter**

So I want to know the intent of the code it; because sometimes it can post to twitter, sometimes can not exist.

```
if ($code == 200) {
    tmhUtilities::pr(json_decode($tmhOAuth->response['response']));
} else { 
    tmhUtilities::pr($tmhOAuth->response['response']);
}

return tmhUtilities;
```

Answer (score 0):

200 is the [HTTP/1.1 return code](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) for a successful request